# Android Spinner drop-down lists distorted on lower API versions

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, backwards-compatibility

When I implement a Spinner in Android post-lollipop API, it looks ugly and distorted when I run it in pre-lollipop versions. The screenshots are attached:

API 23:

[image]

API 16:

[image]

The Spinner is created in the activity's `onCreated` as follows:

```
mViewModeSpinner = new AppCompatSpinner(this);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.playlist_view_options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
mViewModeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
toolbar.addView(mViewModeSpinner);
Toolbar.LayoutParams tlp = new Toolbar.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.END);
mViewModeSpinner.setLayoutParams(tlp);
```

My first guess is that it has something to do with styles, but I have no idea which style exactly should I use and how to apply it to fix this behavior. Btw the same distortions appear in other dropdowns, such as action bar menu.

So how can I make it look the same way in all API's, at least down to 16?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your grade version to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
```

Comment: It really solved my issue. Thanks